# Ubuntu 12.04 - Error encountered in compiling PCRE

Tags: pcre, ubuntu-12.04

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and I am trying to install pcre. However I encountered an error message when I tried to use the command: `sudo make` after the `./configure` command.

I have this error message:

```
/bin/sed: can't read Files/PCRE/pcre-8.30/libpcre.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `Files/PCRE/pcre-8.30/libpcre.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[1]: *** [libpcreposix.la] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dimaz/Downloads/Snort Files/PCRE/pcre-8.30'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `make` chokes on the space in the file name (*Snort Files*). Try to compile it in a directory that does not contain spaces, i.e. by renaming it:

```
mv ~/Downloads/Snort\ Files ~/Downloads/Snort_Files
```